# Как вытащить данные из xml в t-sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

есть xml

```
<root>
 <oid>F602E64B-0156-4E58-8824-616FE1BA0DDE</oid>
 <stype>save</stype>
 <docs>2C3EE067-9D30-4795-95B2-0D8EADEECF9C</docs>
 <docs>CF90C191-5B5D-471E-B414-57D97397595C</docs>
 <docs>276D444C-98D1-4CB4-BB63-CB454A1939D9</docs>
<root>
```

как в sql server можно заселектить узлы docs? многое перепробовал, но ничего не получилось.

Answer (score 1):

Вам надо использовать `cross apply`:

```
Select XmlColumn.query('.', 'nvarchar(256)') docsValue
from XTable cross apply XTable.v.nodes('/root/docs') AS AdditionalTable(XmlColumn)
```

`XTable` - таблица, в которой `xml` поле

`v` - название `xml` поля

Comment: Это не обязательно, т.к. родительская нода объявлена один раз, использование cross apply избыточно.

Answer (score 1):

Обратите внимание на то что тэг `<root>` у вас не закрыт.
Возможно именно поэтому у вас возникли сложности.

Исправив эту ошибку, получить информацию можно так:

```
DECLARE @XML AS XML

SELECT @XML = 
N'<root>
 <oid>F602E64B-0156-4E58-8824-616FE1BA0DDE</oid>
 <stype>save</stype>
 <docs>2C3EE067-9D30-4795-95B2-0D8EADEECF9C</docs>
 <docs>CF90C191-5B5D-471E-B414-57D97397595C</docs>
 <docs>276D444C-98D1-4CB4-BB63-CB454A1939D9</docs>
</root>'

SELECT  xmlData.A.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS docs
FROM    @XML.nodes('root/docs') xmlData(A)
```